# Why didn't the author add “pas” after “parvenir”

Tags: grammaire, négation, double-négation

I'm reading *Le silence de la mer* and it's an old book, looks old like published in the 40s. Anyway, I've just started and ran across the following sentence

> *Nous ne parvenions à voir devant nous rien qu'un abîme fétide*.

I know that one can use *ne...rien* for a negative statement and I see *rien* but the fact that *vois devant* and *nous* fall between *ne* and *rien* I think it would translate to something else. I'm not sure, I've only seen this with like *je connais personne* or *je ne connais personne* or *je veux plus* or *je ne veux plus*. Instead of *pas* one writes *personne* or *plus*. So a nice explanation about this sentence would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a split negative here like "*ne … pas*", "*ne … rien*" or "*ne … personne*" but the restrictive expression *[ne … que](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2466)* so *rien* is optional here.

*Ne … que* means "only".

> *Nous **ne** parvenions à voir devant nous rien **qu**'un abîme fétide.*

means something like:

> We could see in front of us nothing but a foul chasm.

Note that both *devant nous* and *rien* can be removed without breaking either the meaning or the grammar here:

> *Nous **ne** parvenions à voir **qu**'un abîme fétide.*
>
> We were only able to see a foul chasm.

Comment: So, I could write a verb and preprosition etc before ending it with the negative i.e. rien or personne etc.

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear what you are asking, especially as the negative is not only at the end but at the beginning (*ne*). The final word is just part of the negation, not the whole of it. You might want to provide an example of what you would like to write. Note also that the sentence *je connais personne* that you wrote in your question is probably not what you think. It is spoken French only and otherwise strictly equivalent to *je ne connais personne*.

Comment: @NathanielCatchings More than the other items that work like *pas*, I would say that *que* is extremely easy to separate from *ne*, even at long distances. « Je **n**'en ai touché de tes frites, ma chère Jeannette, appétissantes que je les ai trouvées, **que** la seule qui était quand même tombée par terre. »

Comment: P.S. @jlliagre fool chasm

Comment: @Luke foolish mistake ;-) Feel free to correct such errors by the way!